# Boolean Algebra - What is the meaning of f(x) = ∑(N)?

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

Suppose you had:

f(x,y,z) = ∑(2,3,4,5)

What does this represent or map? For each of the variables x,y,z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats same as  sum of products :  $$\begin{align} f(x,y,z) &= \sum m(2,3,4,5)\\~\\&= m_2 + m_3 + m_4 + m5\\~\\&= x'yz' + x'yz+xy'z'+zy'z\end{align}$$